# Talend Component with multiple inputs and unrelated outputs

Tags: talend

using Talend Open Studio, I have a data-processing component, for which I'd appreciate your advice on how to make this possible (a) in a single component and (b) without a dirty workaround - thanks.

***Relating part (a):***
I have two different inputs:

- One Input (with exactly one row) defines some kind of metadata for my processing.
- One Input (with 1...n rows) defines the core data to process.

Currently, I solved this first requirement using two components and passing my metadata to the second component using the globalMap. But it would be nice, if I could integrate both connections into one component.

***Relating part (b):*** After I have read all my input rows, I need to process them all at once. So far, so easy, I could use the end-section - my problem comes here: **After** that processing, I need to create a number of output-rows for a single output connection. Problem is, that Output-rows can only be created in the main-part and there I don't know when the last row was read...

Currently, I solved this counting the input-rows in advance and then, after that number is reached, I create that output. But this seems a really dirty workaround to me, so maybe someone has a solution for that, too?

Thank you for any useful tips!

Comment: I don't understand, what is the component you're referring to ? It would really help if you added screenshots of what you have so far, and sample data with the expected output..

Comment: it is a custom written component.